# How can I use a subdirectory instead of a subdomain?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wordpress, heroku, subdomain, subdirectory

I'm building a rails app that I'll host on Heroku at domain.com. And I'd like to use WordPress for the blog hosted on phpfog, but I don't want to use a subdomain like blog.domain.com. I'd instead prefer to use a subdirectory like domain.com/blog

Its not about SEO...I'm just not a fan of subdomains. Subdirectories are sexier (yeah...I actually said that).

Any idea on how I can reliably accomplish this? Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: I don't know if it's possible, because you can't host Wordpress under Heroku.

Comment: Based on the answers below, along with the bit of research I did, I'm thinking it might better to just roll my own little rails blog engine into my app. I've seen the "build a blog in 15 minutes" rails videos. I don't want to use the scaffolding (I could probably do it without any). My app is kinda blog-esque to begin with anyhow...posts, comments, etc. I'll have to set some kind of user-permissions so that only those with admin accounts can post to the blog though.

Comment: I can't recommend Ryan's railscasts enough for this project, he has examples with a blog so there are a lot of resources which can help you. http://railscasts.com

Comment: Thanks Bruno...I'll check those out. Currently reading Ruby on Rails 3 Tutorial by Michael Hartl.

Comment: FYI there is a Rails blog which is about a quarter as powerful as Wordpress called Refinery CMS https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/projects/refinerycms. It's not WordPress but it's a native solution.

Answer (score 19):

You can use the [rack-reverse-proxy gem](https://github.com/waterlink/rack-reverse-proxy) that neezer found to do this.  First you'll want to add `gem "rack-reverse-proxy", :require => "rack/reverse_proxy"` to your Gemfile and run `bundle install`.  Next, you'll modify your `config.ru` to forward the `/blog/` route to your desired blog:

```
require ::File.expand_path('../config/environment',  __FILE__)

use Rack::ReverseProxy do  
       reverse_proxy /^\/blog(\/.*)$/, 'http://notch.tumblr.com$1', opts={:preserve_host => true}
end

run YourAppName::Application
```

You probably already have the first require statement and the `run YourAppName...` statement.  There are a couple important details that make this work.

First, when you add your desired blog URL, you can't keep the trailing slash on it.  If you do, when someone requests `http://yourdomain.com/blog/`, the gem will forward them to `http://you.yourbloghost.com//` with an extra trailing slash.

Secondly, if the `:preserve_host` option isn't enabled, your blog hosting server will see the request as being for `http://yourdomain.com/blog/` instead of as `http://you.yourbloghost.com` and will return bad results.

You still may have an issue with the CSS or images if the blog uses `/absolute/paths/to/images/`.

Comment: How do you handle the fact that tumblr uses absolute URLs to link to content which include the host name?

Comment: Chris, I'm afraid that I don't have a great solution for that.  I was using Wordpress where you can manually specify the base path it'll use in page content, so I didn't need to address that.  If you want to wade into customizing the source code for rack-reverse-proxy, you could modify it so that it edits the HTML that Tumblr returns..

Comment: Yeah I was playing around trying to figure out how to do that. I was thinking of doing some regex replacing, but it wasn't clear from the docs exactly how that would be done.

Comment: If you want to catch /blog (w/o trailing slash)
reverse_proxy /^\/blog(\/?.*)$/, 'http://notch.tumblr.com$1', opts={:preserve_host => true}

Comment: this works well - how do you alter the wordpress settings so the CSS still works?

Comment: i solved this - this was a HTTPS issue solved by adding wordpress SSL -

Answer (score 3):

I'd say your best bet is to try and do a reverse proxy with Rack middleware (akin to Apache's `mod_proxy`).

A quick Google search revealed this gem ( https://github.com/jaswope/rack-reverse-proxy ), but the author mentions that it's probably not production-ready. Having a Rack middleware proxy should allow you to forward your subdomain `yourdomain.com/blog` to another website `your-phpfog-account.com/wordpress-installation`.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell you can't access the Apache config file with heroku if you could you could use a Rewrite rule.

If you choose not to use heroku you can always do what I detail below.. However if you're not using heroku you could just as easily extract wordpress to the /public/ rails folder and once again use a rewrite rule to get apache to handle the blog requests.

In your apache configuration you'll need to add.

```
RewriteRule ^/blog/?(.*)$ http://somedomain.com/~user/blog/$1 [P,NC,QSA,L]
```

It will redirect all requests to /blog/ to the other server.

Source: http://www.igvita.com/2007/07/04/integrating-wordpress-and-rails/

Comment: I don't think a rewrite is what he wants, since that will change the address in the URL bar to `another-domain.com/blog` instead of `original-domain.com/blog`.

Comment: Ah I see. I'm not familiar with how mod_rewrite works. I just did some googling and assumed that would do what he wanted.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to jplewickeless' answer, I ended up writing custom Rack middelware to replace absolute urls and other paths at the side of the reverse proxy. This guide will get you started on that:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/151-rack-middleware