# Heroku App with a Wordpress Blog

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, wordpress, heroku, hosting

I recently discovered that Heroku now allows PHP which means that a wordpress blog can be hosted on it. I also found this project template: https://github.com/mhoofman/wordpress-heroku

I have a ruby on rails app which is to be hosted on heroku with a domain www.mysite.com, and in that app, i need a way for www.mysite.com/blog to show the wordpress blog.

Can someone help me out, with details on how I can do this?

Comment: What do you mean by `point www.mysite.com/blog to a wordpress based blog.` ?

Comment: i mean, when i go to www.mysite.com/blog, it shows the wordpress blog

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whilst I've not used the new PHP platform I don't think what you're asking for is going to be possible.

When you deploy an application to Heroku it detects the type of application during the push process and sets up the application accordingly, Heroku use Apache to host PHP as you can see from the output in this post http://tjstein.com/2011/09/running-wordpress-on-heroku-and-amazon-rds/ - there's not been any mention of mixing platforms in a single application yet so would imagine that it's not supported.

The nearest you'd get is hosting your site and your blog in two seperate applications with the blog on blog.mysite.com and then put a redirect on www.mysite.com/blog to the blog.mysite.com url.

Comment: as an update to this, I've been looking into some rack middleware that could do this but I've not had much success yet. This would allow you to have 2 seperate applications but serve /blog from the wordpress app.

Comment: I was looking for exactly the same thing.. i pretty much knew that these things would stop me from doing so.. good to be able to confirm.. thanks..

Answer (score 1):

Im Still working on this

the closest to getting a solution is using the reverse proxy gem

see the answer here:

[How can I use a subdirectory instead of a subdomain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6179398/how-can-i-use-a-subdirectory-instead-of-a-subdomain)