# What configuration should be specified to bring different servers in same URL space in CloudBees PaaS

Tags: reverse-proxy, paas, cloudbees

I am trying to use CloudBees PaaS (RUN@CloudBees) to consolidate essentially three different distinct uses under the same URL space:

- root (/) main landing, marketing page
- app (/app) java app running in CloudBees
- blog (/blog) another java app running in cloudbees or possibly outside (example.wordpress.com)

If I was doing it myself in a datacenter or in AWS I would setup a reverse proxy (possibly like Varnish and configure reverse proxy to map the URL space as follows:

- root (/):  www.example.com/ --> CMS running as cloudbees app example-cms.cloudbees.net
- app (/app) java app running in CloudBees www.example.com/app -> app.example.com
- blog (/blog) similarly www.example.com/blog -> example.wordpress.com or exampleblog.cloudbees.net

How can I achieve the same with CloudBees.  Can it be done?  Is this too much to expect from a PaaS vendor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An interesting problem, and a few solutions:

1. Use domains instead of paths (eg blog.example.com etc) - so you can use DNS to direct things
2. Build an app that essentially proxies traffic for you (this could run on cloudbees or elsewhere) - there are lots of ways to do this.
3. Use some routing/proxy service (like CloudFlare) which may let you set up routing rules (so it can proxy traffic).

My preference would always be for number 1 - DNS is a great way to do things like this. 
You can with this approach have /blog similar Urls in your paas application, and have it do a 302 redirect to the real blog.example.com - that kind of gives you a bit of both.

Comment: Thanks.  Number 1 is indeed the simplest.  The search engine impact is also not bad as your main URL will get the credit for articles in the redirect (302, as you suggest is better than 301).  Only issue is once the user is redirected they will use the blogs.example.com URL to share which is not what one would want.  Still solution 1 seems quite easy to implement.

Comment: BTW if someone wants to add reverse proxy to their rails based application I found [rack-reverse-proxy gem](https://github.com/jaswope/rack-reverse-proxy) to be very good.  Also see [jplewicki's](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1038045/jplewicke) answer on [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6179398/how-can-i-use-a-subdirectory-instead-of-a-subdomain)