# Rails/Rack... Rack::ReverseProxy Causing Request Timeout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rack, reverse-proxy

I'm think I'm in over my head and can't figure out how to debug or where to go from here?!! Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

**Problem:**

- Development Environment: everything works
- Production: I get "Request timeout" error

**Goal:**

Have "www.site.com/blog" show content from "blog.site.com" without a redirect/changing browser URL

**Setup**

- www.site.com is a Rails App on Heroku
- blog.site.com is WordPress on
  Bluehost

So I don't have access to server config

**Approach**

Use [rack-reverse-proxy](https://github.com/jaswope/rack-reverse-proxy) gem as described in [How can I use a subdirectory instead of a subdomain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6179398/how-can-i-use-a-subdirectory-instead-of-a-subdomain) by [jplewicke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1038045/jplewicke)

**Implementation**

Gemfile

```
gem "rack-reverse-proxy", :require => "rack/reverse_proxy"
```

config.ru (just before run *AppName*::Application)

```
use Rack::ReverseProxy do
  reverse_proxy(/^\/blog(\/.*)$/,'http://blog.site.com$1',
  opts = {:preserve_host => true})
end
```

config/routes.rb

```
match "/blog" => redirect("/blog/")
```

**Results/Problem**

It works great in development on my machine but when I put it in production it times out. Not only does it time out but afterwards the entire application gets hung up or something, i.e. every request times out even www.site.com (which worked before trying blog.site.com). After about 5-10mins www.site.com works again but blog.site.com times out.

**Logs**

> 2013-03-05 05:54:19+00:00 app web.1     - - Started GET "/resource"
>   for 66.108.140.26/cpe-66-108-140-26.nyc.res.rr.com at 2013-03-05
>   05:54:19 +0000
>
> 2013-03-05 05:54:19+00:00 heroku router - - at=info
>   method=GET path=/blog host=www.site.com
>   fwd="66.108.140.26/cpe-66-108-140-26.nyc.res.rr.com" dyno=web.1
>   queue=0 wait=0ms connect=1ms service=7ms status=301 bytes=105
>
> 2013-03-05 05:54:49+00:00 heroku router - - at=error code=H12
>   desc="Request timeout" method=GET path=/blog/
>   host=www.site.com
>   fwd="66.108.140.26/cpe-66-108-140-26.nyc.res.rr.com" dyno=web.1
>   queue=0ms wait=0ms connect=2ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0

**debug**

I tried turning on debugging in production...

config/environments/production.rb

```
config.consider_all_requests_local = true
config.log_level = :debug
```

but nothing really shows up just a generic,

> Application Error... your page could not be served... try again.... check logs.

It's the only thing that kind of makes sense since it is working in developement

Any suggestions or ideas on what to do?  Thanks!

Comment: `config.assets.debug = true` just turns on Rails asset debugging, did you mean to enable debug logging in `production.rb`? If so, use `config.log_level = :debug`

Comment: @stuart thanks. That was a typo in the question. I've corrected it above. `config.log_level = :debug` is the current setting.

Comment: How long does it take for the proxy to load pages for you in development? Heroku has some information about this ['Request Timeout' error](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/request-timeout) which may be of use. Could it just be that proxying those pages in the Heroku-deployed environment takes longer?

Comment: It's pretty much instant. The local server logs don't show a time? But it's less than a second. I guess it could just be it takes 30+ seconds in production but is that normal for production to be an order of magnitude slower?

Comment: So I was unable to get this to work. I ended up running it through nginx and doing the reverse proxy from there. Thanks for your help @StuartM

Comment: @haley - could you please elaborate on how you got the reverse proxy on nginx on heroku? I have the same set up and am running into the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I just setup this on rails 4. It was working on all subdirectory using:

```
use Rack::ReverseProxy do
  reverse_proxy_options preserve_host: true
  reverse_proxy '/blog', 'http://grav.somedomain.net/'
end
```

but it was responding a permanent redirect (301) when visiting /blog without subdirectory.

To solve the problem simply rewrite /blog to /blog/home and make sure to add this alias link in your blog!

```
require 'rack/rewrite'
use Rack::Rewrite do
  rewrite   '/blog',  '/blog/home'
end
```

Maybe someone can tell us if this hypothesis is true: It is frequent that the blog engine have a redirect on the home which break the proxy maybe.

Have a nice one!