# How do I bolt a Wordpress blog onto a /blog URL for a PHP Yii site running on Heroku?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, heroku, yii2

I'm thinking of modifying the .htaccess file to create a reverse proxy, or to forward requests in Yii, but I'm not sure. It might be similar to this answer, but for PHP instead of Rails.

[How can I use a subdirectory instead of a subdomain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6179398/how-can-i-use-a-subdirectory-instead-of-a-subdomain)

Is there a standard Composer plugin for PHP/Yii for setting up a reverse-proxy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Procfile`

```
web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 -l runtime/logs/app.log -C httpd_include.conf web/
```

`httpd_include.conf`

```
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm
# For blog
LoadModule proxy_html_module libexec/mod_proxy_html.so
LoadModule ssl_module libexec/mod_ssl.so
LoadModule xml2enc_module libexec/mod_xml2enc.so
SSLProxyEngine on
ProxyRequests off
ProxyPass /blog https://shopwiz2.wordpress.com
ProxyPassReverse /blog https://shopwiz2.wordpress.com
ProxyHTMLURLMap https://shopwiz2.wordpress.com /blog
<Location /blog>
  ProxyPassReverse /
  ProxyHTMLEnable On
  ProxyHTMLURLMap / /blog
  RequestHeader    unset  Accept-Encoding
  #LogLevel proxy:debug
</Location>
```

Reference:

http://www.apachetutor.org/admin/reverseproxies

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-php-settings#using-a-custom-application-level-apache-configuration

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_proxy.html