# How to have Wordpress on a /blog directoy of a Flask app running on Heroku

Tags: python, wordpress, heroku, nginx, flask

I have an app running on Heroku that use the domain example.com and a blog running on another host, Dreamhost, that uses the domain blog.example.com. For SEO purposes, I want to have the blog appear on example.com/blog. How could I achieve this? My Googling powers have failed me, although it appears that using some Nginx rewrites could be the solution. Any help is appreciated. Since it is for SEO purposes, I simple redirect won't do. I found this solution: [How can I use a subdirectory instead of a subdomain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6179398/how-can-i-use-a-subdirectory-instead-of-a-subdomain), but is specific to Ruby on Rails.

Answer (score 2):

I am confused with what you are asking though, since Heroku a PaaS platform installing a webserver like nginx is not ease, i am guessing you may be using any nginx heroku buildpack with `example.com` pointing to nginx server in heroku, if these are correct then,
creating a reverse proxy in nginx will route sites accessing`example.com/blog` to the address given

```
server {
  server_name example.com;
  location /blog/{
     proxy_pass blog.example.com;  # expect request timeout from example.com -> this server
     proxy_set_header Host $host;  # or replace with blog.example.com
     proxy_pass_request_headers on;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution!! Small comment from my side: `proxy_pass https://blog.example.com;`